# Controlling PWM from Web interface

Tags: python, html, pi

I'm new with web interface development.
Currently I'm using a Raspberry pi and I would like to control PWM from the website.
The idea is, as the button 'on' is clicked (each time) from the web interface, the pwm increase by 1 hence the LED become brighter and vice versa.
However, my code doesn't work and I cannot find any example for me to refer.

What's is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much for your help, i'm really appreciate it

Part of the code is as follow:

```
@app.route("/<deviceName>/<action>")
def action(deviceName, action):
    DC = 0
    pwm_counter = 0
    Length = 220
    Width = 100
    Power = 0
    Wattage = 5000
    if deviceName == 'ledRed':
        if action == "on":
            pwm_counter = pwm_counter + 1
            if pwm_counter > 100:
                pwm_counter = 100
            DC = DC + 1
            if DC > 100:
                DC = 100
            Power = round((((DC / 100) * Wattage) / (Length * Width)), 6)
        if action == "off":
            pwm_counter = pwm_counter - 1
            if pwm_counter<0:
                pwm_counter=0
            DC = DC - 1
            if DC<0:
                DC=0
            Power = round((((DC / 100) * Wattage) / (Length * Width)), 6)

    ledRedSts = GPIO.input(ledRed)


    templateData = {
        'ledRed'  : ledRedSts
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
    return pwm_counter, DC, Power

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1025, debug=True)
    while True:
        UpdateScreen(DC, Power)
    
        pwm_output.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm_counter)
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with web interface development in python, but I did notice that you have two `return` statements at the end of your `action` function. Which means **only the first** `return` statement gets run and the second one **never gets run**.

Comment: The variable `ledRed`, which you use here: `ledRedSts = GPIO.input(ledRed)` is not defined, maybe it's part of the URL, but as variable it's not defined.  
You could simplify your code: `pwm_counter = min(pwm_counter+1, 100)` and `DC=min(DC+1, 100)` for ON and for OFF it could be  `pwm_counter = max(pwm_counter-1, 0)` and `DC=max(DC-1, 0)`, `Power` could be calculated after the `if...else` block (since it's the same for ON and OFF, unless there will be more actions and you don't want to calculate it for them). As mentioned you have 2 returns, only the 1st one will be executed.